# Error while using sqlcmd with Start-Job in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

When I'm executing this command in PowerShell, everything works fine:

```
sqlcmd -S dwh -i ".\script.sql" -o ".\log.txt"
```

However, when I'd like to set up several jobs, the following command doesn't work:

```
Start-Job -Name TestSqlCmd -ScriptBlock {sqlcmd -S dwh -i ".\script.sql" -o ".\log.txt"}
```

I got the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file .\script.sql (Reason: The system cannot find the path specified).
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: Error: ...ath specified).:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Could you help me with that issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you start a job, the script block inside that job actually runs in a new PS session. Therefore, you are nor longer cd'ed into the same path, but you can do the following to fix that:

```
Start-Job -Name TestSqlCmd -ScriptBlock {
    Param(
        $path
    )
    echo "$path\script.sql" 
    echo "$path\log.txt"
} -ArgumentList (Get-Location).Path
```

Or just add a full path in the script-block itself.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 7 has a `-workingdirectory` parameter too.  Actually it looks like start-job or start-threadjob in ps 7 respects the current directory anyway.